# DataContractSerializer, why is "this" not upcasted?

Tags: c#, f#, datacontractserializer

I'm working on a server coded with F#. This server connects to a WCF REST service coded with C#.

**My F# project is referencing the C# assembly.**

In my C# I have `namespace GlobalNotificationService.DTO`:

```cs
public class Producer
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Name", IsRequired = true, Order = 1)]
    public string Name {get; set;}
    ...
    public string Marshal()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (XmlTextWriter textWriter = new XmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(sb)))
        {
            DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(DTO.Producer));                
            serializer.WriteObject(textWriter, this); //THIS IS THE LINE THROWING THE EXECPTION
            textWriter.Flush();
            textWriter.Close();
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

In my F# I have `namespace ServiceCore`:

```ml
type Producer(file_name) as this =
    inherit DTO.Producer()
    ...
    member public this.SerializedXML
        with get() = this.Marshal() //Call to C# assembly
```

So the code does compile but I get this exception at run time *(look for the comment above)*.

> Type **'ServiceCore.Producer'** with data contract name
>   **'Producer:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ServiceCore'** is not
>   expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not
>   known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using
>   the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of
>   known types passed to DataContractSerializer.

### The question is:

Why is "this" of type **ServiceCode.Producer** *(F#)* even though it should have been upcasted to **DTO.Producer** *(C#)* since the method is in the **DTO.Producer** class and that I'm explicitly asking for a **DTO.Producer** serialization?

### Complementary question:

Why do we even care about the fact that the call is coming from a descendant class? Our "this" reference should still be up-casted and be of type **DTO.Producer**.

It doesn't make a lot of sence to me, am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're explicitly instantiating the DCS in Marshal, you could change its definition to to be

```
public string Marshal<T>() 
...
    new DataContractSerializer(typeof<T>) ...
```

and then the F# code could call Marshal with its own subtype.

Answer (score 3):

There is no automatic upcast in serialization.  You have to tell the serializer explicitly what types are equivalent to other types.

For the base type (DTO.Producer) you have to add a

```
[KnownType(typeof(ServiceCode.Producer)]
```

You might also be able to try and explicitly cast the object to DTO.Producer in the Marshal call, but that might not work.

Comment: Actually, some times types *are* silently upcast, but that is usually to handle invisible proxy types, such as from EF or NH; in *general* what you say is true.

Comment: Well I'm trying to serialize a DTO.Producer not a ServiceCore.Producer serialization. I also can't add a KnownType sine the WCF service is not aware of the F# code and making it aware would create a circular dependency.

Comment: It's not a circular dependency.  I can have a derived class's name in a [KnownType] tag.  The problem is you are calling .Marshal() from a ServiceCore.Producer object, so that's what it thinks it is.  You can try downcasting it inside Marshal() which might get you what you want.

Comment: @Joe: you can't mix F# and C# in the same assembly. It is a circular dependency.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Yes, agreed.  Within the same assembly you can reference similar types.  Which is why we generally pull our contracts into specific assemblies when we have these kinds of serialization inheritance issues.

Comment: Actually, this will probably work, you just need to decorate the F# type with `[KnownType(typeof(DTO.Producer)]` or IMO just skip creating another type in F# altogether.

Comment: @leppie: That won't work.  [KnownType] has to be on the base in this scenario.  It's not bi-directional like that.

Comment: It looks like you can also avoid the dependency by changing `Marshal` to be `Marshal<T>` where you pass the concrete subtype `T` that the DCS needs to know about.

Comment: @Brian Your guess was a good one, you should write an actual answer so I can validate it :)

Comment: Thank everybody for your help.